# Access Gmail Inbox with Gmail API for arbitrary user on server backend

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gmail-api

I have a google app engine python project registered and running under my own gmail account (myself@gmail.com). A third party service will send a confirmation email to another email account I control (myotheraccount@appdomainemail.com) that is hosted on a google apps domain (not a gmail.com email account).

Inside the python backend for this google apps project, I need to access the google apps domain email account, search for an email in that account based on message content, and then forward it to a third email address.

My question is, is it possible to access a google apps domain email account using the Gmail API?

Also is there any way to access an arbitrary email address from the backend without any kind of complicated authentication process? For example make a gmail api call with the email address and the password (because its on the backend, there's no risk exposing the login credentials).

Comment: none of that is possible with the api. you must have refresh tokens saved for each user.

Comment: Would this be possible if i moved the google app engine project to be under the app domain email address (if that's even possible) ? Otherwise do I have to write my own webcrawler to do this?

Comment: Looks like it might be possible using python libs imaplib, smtplib, and email. Theoretically it looks like I can connect to the apps domain gmail account, list all the messages, find one i want, use that message's information, and use smtplib to send a new one to any email address.

Comment: yes with smtp you could if you know the passwords. that doesnt use oauth2 and appears plain SASL is supported so users can use older email clients: https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview